# Trying to Insert Rows and Rollback to last valid entry

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert rows to a table.  When the insert encounters an error, I want the insertion to rollback to the last successfully inserted row.

database schema:

```
DEPTNO   NUMBER(3),   
DNAME   VARCHAR2(16),   
LOC    VARCHAR2(16),
```

Only the first 3 rows should be inserted because there is an error in row 4

```
INSERT INTO dept VALUES (10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');    
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (20, 'RESEARCH',   'DALLAS');    
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (30, 'SALES',      'CHICAGO');   
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (40, 'OPERATIONS', 'WASHINGTON (D.C.)');    
INSERT INTO dept   VALUES (50, 'MARKETING', 'BOSTON');



SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
set autocommit on;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO dept VALUES (10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');    
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (20, 'RESEARCH',   'DALLAS');    
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (30, 'SALES',      'CHICAGO');   
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (40, 'OPERATIONS', 'WASHINGTON (D.C.)');    
INSERT INTO dept   VALUES (50, 'MARKETING', 'BOSTON');



EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

I expect the first 3 rows to be inserted into the database.

Comment: AFAIK the only easy way to do this is to just insert the records one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need auto commit to be 'on'
and change rollback with COMMIT

BEGIN

INSERT INTO dept VALUES (10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (20, 'RESEARCH',   'DALLAS');
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (30, 'SALES',      'CHICAGO');
INSERT  INTO dept  VALUES (40, 'OPERATIONS', 'WASHINGTON (D.C.)');
INSERT INTO dept   VALUES (50, 'MARKETING', 'BOSTON');

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
COMMIT;

END;

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the "rollback" to "commit" at the exception part.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a source table created as:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT_ORIG AS
SELECT 10 AS DEPTNO, 'ACCOUNTING' AS DNAME, 'NEW YORK' AS LOC FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 20, 'RESEARCH'  , 'DALLAS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 30, 'SALES'     , 'CHICAGO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 40, 'OPERATIONS', 'WASHINGTON (D.C.)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 50, 'MARKETING' , 'BOSTON' FROM DUAL;
```

then you may consider the following PL/SQL block to insert the desired records in which you'll have the first three of them only, because of the exceeding length for the fourth row with length value 17 of `loc` column :

```
SQL> BEGIN
      FOR C IN ( SELECT * FROM dept_orig ORDER BY deptno )
      LOOP
       BEGIN
         INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (c.deptno, c.dname, c.loc);
         COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK; EXIT;
       END;
      END LOOP;
   END;
   /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

 SQL> SELECT * FROM dept ORDER BY deptno;

 DEPTNO  DNAME      LOC
 ------  ---------- ----------
 10      ACCOUNTING NEW YORK
 20      RESEARCH   DALLAS
 30      SALES      CHICAGO
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48ca69619fcc6141a9244fca3caf16b8)</kbd>